# how to call onClick event on select box in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i am displaying a select box

```
<%= select(:grade,:id,@distinct_grade_list,:multiple => true)%>
```

I want to call a function on click event , like

```
<%= select(:grade,:id,@distinct_grade_list,:multiple => true, :onclick => "callMe()")%>
```

or

```
<%= select(:grade,:id,@distinct_grade_list,:multiple => true, :onchange => "callMe()")%>
```

where as my function is

```
<head>
        <script>
            function callMe()
            {
                alert("call me called")
            }
        </script>
    </head>
```

but the alert never executes , i dont get any error in browser console ,
what can be causing this ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ref [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M002296)

I think you should use `onchange()` insteaed of `onclick()` also your `html_options` should be the `5th parameter`

```
<%= select(:grade, :id, @distinct_grade_list, 
                        {}, 
                        {:multiple => true, :onchange => "callMe()"}) %>
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with onclick or onchange , the only prob is the one you metioned about the html options being 5th parameter

Comment: could you please be available on some mail or chat id , i am newbie on rails and having too many issues

Comment: do email me at `salilgaikwad@gmail.com`, i am not active all the day but i'll try my best to help you. but i'll recommend you to stick to http://stackoverflow.com/ as there are number of experts to answer your queries.